# Laravel 5: How can I get automatic DI via constructors of custom classes?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, ioc-container, laravel-5

The Laravel documentation states:  "you may simply "type-hint" the dependency in the constructor of a class that is resolved by the container, including controllers, event listeners..."

The key words here are "a class that is resolved by the container" - I have been trying to reproduce this with my own custom classes (services, repositories, handlers, etc.) and I can't quite figure it out.  The controllers (and other classes) are resolved via the container which handles the automatic injection of any dependencies.  See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L53

My question is how do I achieve this same functionality with my own class structure.  It's not as simple as binding classes to the IoC and resolving them via getters.  I am wondering if anyone has maybe set something like this up in their app and would be willing to share their technique :)

It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A container resolves object **graphs**. So you need to have your class on the graph.

If controllers are handled by Laravel's container, then there you go: inject your service in your controller and Laravel will handle it for you.

By "handle it for you" I mean it will create & inject the dependencies of the controller, and the dependencies of the dependencies, and … This is transitive.

For example:

- UserController

  - UserService

    - UserRepository (or whatever other class)

So the question is: where do you want to inject your class?

- in a controller: Laravel will handle that
- in another object: goto "where do you want to inject your class?"
- in a "root" object that is not a controller (e.g. a test class, a Command class, a …): here you will need Laravel to create the object. It may be easy or not, I don't know Laravel enough…